# Switching users in a shell script

Tags: shell

```
OS: Ubunut 14.04
```

I have a shell script, and I would like to run a portion of the script as a different user. I tried adding the following to my script:

```
echo 'user_password' | su user_name
cd ~
ls -l
```

But I am getting the following message:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that it is a bad security practice to store a user's password in plaintext.

If you really want to read the password from STDIN, you can use the `-S` option of `sudo`, which doesn't seem to have a counterpart in the `su` command.

For a better solution, that doesn't involve storing the password in plaintext, see the answers on this [askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294736/run-a-shell-script-as-another-user-that-has-no-password).

Comment: I ma using this as an example. My script installs a rails/ruby over a LAMP stack. So, I am not really storing the password. The script earlier asks for a username, and a password for that user. It then creates the user, and adds the user to sudoers. Now, I want to be logged on as this user to be able to continue setting up ruby/rails and would rather do the whole thing from a single script

Comment: OK. If you do `echo $password | sudo -u username -S yourcommand`, it should work.